# can we give ouput port variable in sensitive list in system c?

Tags: c++, systemc

As we know that in sensitive list we can give an input port variables such as:

```
  sc_in<bool> a,b;
  sc_out<bool>out;

  SC_THREAD(my_thread);
  sensitive<<a;// it works normal ..
```

But can we write?

```
  SC_THREAD(my_thread);
  sensitive<<out;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add sc_out port to sensitivity.